# Django e-mail errors silenced even with fail_silently=False

Tags: python, django, email

I've been trying to capture any exception raised while sending e-mails, but even explicitly using `fail_silently=False` doesn't do the trick. I'll explain my use-case in detail below.

I'm using Django 2.2.16 (upgrading to 3 is not an option for the moment, because of some external libraries). Python 3.8.

The code sending e-mails is as follows (it comes from a class extending `EmailMultiAlternatives`):

```
try:
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.info("Timeout: %i", settings.EMAIL_TIMEOUT)
    # Ignore fail_silently and always show errors
    count_sent = super().send(fail_silently=False)
    logger.info("Mail sent: %i.", count_sent)
    return count_sent
except (smtplib.SMTPException, socket.error, Exception):
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.exception("An error occured while trying to send an e-mail.")
    return 0
```

If I, for e.g., explicitly configure a wrong host name or username for the SMTP server, the code above won't capture such exceptions (e.g. a socket error in the first example, an authentication error in the second).

The logged information will be:

```
Timeout: 10
Mail sent: 0.
```

**Note:** The class doesn't modify any connection method from the parent class. The code above appears in the `send` method of my custom class.

If I replace the line calling `send` and use:

```
try:
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.info("Timeout: %i", settings.EMAIL_TIMEOUT)
    from django.core.mail import get_connection
    conn = get_connection(fail_silently=False)
    count_sent = conn.send_messages([self])
    logger.info("Mail sent: %i.", count_sent)
    return count_sent
except (smtplib.SMTPException, socket.error, Exception):
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.exception("An error occured while trying to send an e-mail.")
    return 0
```

That code captures any socket or e-mail error (adding `Exception` captures anything else). The resulting logger information for an authentication error would be as expected:

```
Timeout: 10
An error occured while trying to send an e-mail.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/code/app/email_helper.py", line 130, in send_in_thread
    count_sent = conn.send_messages([self])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 103, in send_messages
    new_conn_created = self.open()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 70, in open
    self.connection.login(self.username, self.password)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 734, in login
    raise last_exception
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 723, in login
    (code, resp) = self.auth(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 646, in auth
    raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, resp)
smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful')
```

After reading through the source code of the function `send` in Django's `EmailMessage` I cannot find a reason for the initial code not to work. The code for v3 can be found in this link (it has not changed since 2.2.16): https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/mail/message.py

`send` basically does `return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])`. And the connection is obtained using `django.core.mail.get_connection` as in my second approach.

Would someone know best why in this scenario the first code doesn't capture exceptions, while the second does? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you included at least one recipient. If you haven't, the first piece of code will just not send anything and would log exactly that you've got. The second example would attempt to send an email anyway, and you'll get an authentication error since you've given a wrong username etc.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yes, both examples are run with the same data, with valid recipients in `to` and `bcc`, proper `subject`, `body` and HTML alternative. This is part of a working system and I'm forcing the errors described to see how the it would behave. When the e-mails are sent (i.e. I didn't force any error, I can see the e-mail in the inbox)

Comment: @Ricci did you manage to resolve that question?

Comment: Sorry @EugZol, I didn't find an answer to the question. The final code derived from this, but essentially I kept the second approach.